# How can i add an attribute to XML element for parent tag using JAXB annotations

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

How can I add an attribute of lane in Events tag (for every child tags I wrote separate class)?

Here is the sample format:

```
<TestRequest>
     <Constraints>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <ServiceFlags>
            <ServiceFlag code = "" />
        </ServiceFlags>
     </Constraints>
    <Events>
        <Event type="Pickup">
            <Location>
                <Zip></Zip>
                <Country></Country>
            </Location>
        </Event>
        <Event type="Drop">
            <Location>
                <Zip></Zip>
                <Country></Country>
            </Location>
        </Event>
    </Events>
</TestRequest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html).
First you create your `XmlAdapter`, for ex. `EventAdapter`.
Then you add the annotation  `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EventAdapter.class)` where you define your `@XmlAttribute(name = "type")`.

Comment: Hi, crevier can u please explain with one example, so that it will help to me.